# How to use Kubernetes secret object stringData to store base64 encoded privateKey

Tags: shell, kubernetes, yaml, helm3

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "backstage.fullname" . }}-backend
type: Opaque
stringData:
  GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE:|-
{{ .Values.auth.ghApp.privateKey | quote | b64dec | indent 2 }}
```

Getting `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: could not find expected ':'` as the result when

trying to store a base64 encoded string to `GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE`

My application (backstage) is using helm charts to map the env secret.

I keep having trouble with storing/passing multi-line RSA. private key,

Currently trying to base64 encoded private key into one-liner, but still failed at validating the secret file.  Would love to know other approach like passing a file with key written on it?

BTW, I use `GITHUB_PRVATE_KEY=$(echo -n $GITHUB_PRVATE_KEY | base64 -w 0)` and

```
helm_overrides="$helm_overrides --set auth.ghApp.clientSecret=$GITHUB_PRVATE_KEY"
```

at GitHub action to encoded the private key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increase the indent to 4:

```
...
stringData:
  GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE: |-
{{ .Values.auth.ghApp.privateKey | quote | b64dec | indent 4 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, syntax is good now, now I'm getting ```illegal base64 data at input byte 0```,  any insight?  I think I should used base64 encoded key in `data` instead of `stringData`

Comment: If your private key is plain text, you do not need to quote nor encode it. Just make sure the indent is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE:|-`

You need a space in there `GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE: |-`

Also not sure why you have a `b64dec` in there but I don't think that's the immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks! good catch!   Because I passed a base 64 encode to ```GH_APP_PRIVATEKEY_BASE: |-``` so b64dec is there to decode, I hope

Comment: Btw, the problem still persists after adding space...